# Roslyn dynamically complie methods on-demand

Tags: c#, roslyn

Does anyone have some pointers to load methods dynamically using Roslyn?

In my server I want to be able to access business rules in c# methods and compile and run them dynamically as required. In my case I will have 10,000's of rules. Only a fraction of the rules will be accessed in one run (and will not change during the run). The rules need to be able to call each other.

A rule would be something like:
UpdatePriceSnippet.cs:

```
public static void UpdatePrice(string productId)
{
   if (productId.StartsWith("X"))
   {
      int price = GetPrice(productId);
      ABCCommon.DbUpdateProductPrice(productId, price*1.1);
   }
}
```

GetPriceSnippet.cs:

```
public static int GetPrice(string ProductId)
{
   return ABCCommon.DbReadProductPrice(productId);
}
```

In this case the UpdatePrice method would be complied on-demand (by loading and compiling "{method}Snippet.cs"). And likewise GetPrice would only be compiled if productId starts with "X". ABCCommon would be a pre-compiled assembly with helper methods for the rules.

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScript interpreter like JInt? which is very small and executes faster, you can access and use C# objects in JInt. Benefit of JavaScript is it will be usable on client side if you plan to use ajax based UI based updates.

Comment: That probably won't be faster than compiling everything normally.

Comment: Thanks @AkashKava. That could be an alternative. It just seems roslyn is so close to doing what I want and I much prefer C# syntax for the rules.

Comment: @SLaks that's probably correct. I am not too concerned about performance, more that rules can be changed and tested quickly, otherwise they could just exist in the normal C# base code.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know the types of parameters and the return type of a method without at least looking at the signature of the method?

Comment: Also, if you're not concerned about performance, why don't you compile everything on every change?